# Rasterize polygons on GPU for hit-testing

Tags: performance, algorithm, gpu, polygon, raster

## Task

Perform many hit-tests on polygons. I have about 10,000 polygons with 1,000 points each. About 100,000,000 hit-tests will be performed against these polygons. The polygons may touch each other but never overlap.

## Solution

Simple point-in-polygon test for every hit-test.

## Problem

Far too slow.

## Improvement

Rasterize the polygons and check which polygon the pixel of the hit-tests belongs to.

## New problem

Rasterization of the polygons is slow. I'm using this algorithm: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/

## Idea

Rasterize the polygons on the GPU since it's optimized for this task and can perform it in hardware.

## Question

What do you think about my idea and can you give me advice where to start? Will it lead to high performance?

## Sidenote

The area is sparsly covered with polygons. I want to maintain a list of pixels instead of a bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried rasterization with standard graphic libraries (GDI, Direct** for Windows, OpenGL etc)?

Comment: These libraries always paint directly on the screen. I don't want to paint. I want to perform hit-tests.

Comment: No, they can paint to in-memory context (select bitmap in MemDC). This is effective way to solve problems like yours, if polygon coordinates are in reasonable limits

Comment: How would I get the pixels hit by the polygon? Will I have to go through the whole bitmap? Wouldn't that be inefficient (imagine a thin horseshoe as polygon)?

Comment: Why would you want the pixels hit by the polygon? You could just index into the bitmap at whatever place you were doing a hit test, and get just 1 pixel that shows you whether it hit or not.

Comment: Are the polygons in 2D? Are they connected? Can you post an example image?

Comment: I need to know which polygon is hit.

Comment: p.s.  Are they convex? I suppose you are already doing a quick check if a point is in the square/cube spanned by the coordinate min/max before doing a detailed check?

Comment: The polygons are not convex. :-(

Comment: Fill bitmap with 0 (black color). Draw (fill) the first polygon with color 0x000001, the second one with color 0x000002 etc. Pick a pixel at hit-test coordinates. Its color is for polygon number (if they don't intersect)

Comment: Another approach is to use a spatial database like PostGIS. They can do efficient point-in-polygon queries using R-trees among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer suggests to use the GPU if you can:
[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Your case seems to be dominated by the hit tests, which are O(1) with rasterization. GPUs are able to rasterize to memory, but I am not aware of any GPU / rendering API that is able to work with a list of points. Also, with a list of points, you may lose the O(1) runtime for the hit check. You may be able to save some memory by using a 16 bit raster buffer (not sure if that's feasible with your GPU setup -- but you only seem to need 10000 colors).

Comment: I went with GDI and it's incredibly fast!